# populating values in handsontable table using watir

Tags: watir, handsontable

How can I automate the task of populating values in handsontable using Watir?

I have list of values in excel. Watir reads these values and then populates handsontable in their respective column. The challenge is none of the fields in handsontable has an identification property, which makes the job more difficult.

---

Pls find HTML Code as requested:

```
<html>
<head>
  <body>
      <form action="importer.php" method="POST">
        <div class="selections">
          <div id="buildingSelector" style="display: none;">
            <script src="js/importer/buildingselect.js">
            <script type="text/javascript">
              <div id="importdata" class="handsontable">
                <div class="wtHolder" style="position: relative; display: table;">
                 <div class="wtHider" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1904px;">
                   <div class="wtSpreader">
                     <table class="htCore" style="display: table;">
                       <colgroup>
                         <thead>
                           <tr>
                            <thead>
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td class=""></td>
                                   <td class=""></td>
                                   <td class=""></td>
                                 </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide link to the page, a similar one, or relevant HTML. Also, please provide relevant Ruby code.

Comment: Assuming you are working with a table similar to that on http://handsontable.com/, locating elements by index seems safe enough. Though I think the bigger problem is getting the textarea to appear. Using Element#double_click did not seem to work for me.

Comment: What about triggering keypress with the enter key?